# How to hide Python console while installing modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How could I make a script that would install modules but silently? I've tried the `.pyw` method, but it doesn't work when installing modules.

Here's what I've have:

```
import os

os.system("pip install module1")
os.system("pip install module2")
os.system("pip install module3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we have to consider which output you trying to *hide*: **stdout**, **stderr**

The following code will *hide* stdout but will still show stderr.

```py
import subprocess
batcmd = "pip install numpy"
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
>>> result
b'Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\\users\\xxxx\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python38\\site-packages (1.20.2)\r\n'
```

The following will hide all output:
`pip install numpy 1,2>nul`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the -q or --quiet flag already in pip. However, if you use the flag once like this,

```
pip install module1 -q
```

then any warning, error or critical logging output may appear.

If you wish to block all output no matter what (including all level logging), use the -q flag three times like so:

```
pip install module1 -q -q -q
```

To make sure that you aren't prompted for input (in a y/n prompt situation), use the `--no-input` flag.

In summary, your new code should look something like this:

```
import os

os.system("pip install module1 -q -q -q --no-input")
os.system("pip install module2 -q -q -q --no-input")
os.system("pip install module3 -q -q -q --no-input")
```

`-q` documentation: https://pip-python3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pip.html#cmdoption-q
`--no-input` documentation: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#cmdoption-no-input

Comment: curious, do you know if that suppress instances where it forces you to type in a 'y/n' response?

Comment: I'm not sure, but a way of getting around the y/n response problem is with this solution: yes | pip install <package>

Comment: In that case, you could forget using the `os` library and use subprocess instead and combine the two answers. Something like `subprocess.call("yes|pip install module1 -q -q -q", shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for conveniently exists in pip already:  using the `--quiet / -q` flag:

```
pip install module1 --quiet
```

**Edit**: This only seems to give less output, not completely silent.

Using Kailash E's answer, you could try the following with the `subprocess` library:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("yes|pip install module1 -q -q -q", shell=True)
```

Comment: I just found a better implementation, I'm updating my answer now.